# Sort doesn't work properly for cells with references to other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have two tables in Excel 2010, the second table has the last column filled with cells that reference the last column cells from the first table:

For instance, the value of the first cell in the last column in the second table `= (=F4)`, so it references `F4` cell which exists in the first table, the value of the second cell down `= (=F14)`, the third one `= (=F19)`, and so on.

As a result, the last column in the second table will sort incorrectly (false result). Is there a solution to this problem ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: for example: you can copy the _values_ to another column, and sort it

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the references to the cells. As belisarius commented, you can copy and *paste values* over top of the formula cells

Alternately, you can click on the cells with formulas, select the references in the formula bar and hit F9, this will create the formula with absolute values rather than references.